# DatePickerFragment+EditText implementation with AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

Im making reminder app. I need to create ALertDialog with 3 EditText's(task's title, date, time). It doesnt work because this code is outdated since end of 2016

```
 //Main dialog class

    public class AddingTaskDialogFragment extends DialogFragment  {

    private AddingTaskListener addingTaskListener;

    public interface AddingTaskListener {
        void onTaskAdded(ModelTask newTask);
        void onTaskAddingCancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            addingTaskListener = (AddingTaskListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement AddingTaskListener");
        }
    }

    //Main Method

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_task, null);

        //Creating 3 TextEdits (TItle, date, time)

        final TextInputLayout tilTitle = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskTitle);
        final EditText etTitle = tilTitle.getEditText();

        TextInputLayout tilDate = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskDate);
        final EditText etDate = tilDate.getEditText();

        final TextInputLayout tilTime = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskTime);
        final EditText etTime = tilTime.getEditText();



        tilTitle.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.task_title));
        tilDate.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.task_date));
        tilTime.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.task_time));

        builder.setView(container);

        final ModelTask task=new ModelTask();
        final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+1);

        //The most interesting part

        etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (etDate.length() == 0) {
                    etDate.setText(" ");
                }
```

Error with DatePickerFragment : Fragments should be 
 static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous 
 classes are not static
                      Btw i found this version in 3 year old android developing course and now it's not working (even if you create static class or make individual file for class, etc) I tried many things to do

```
DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    etDate.setText(Utils.getDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    etDate.setText(null);
                }
            };
            datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerFragment");
        }
    });
    //the same thing with TImePickerFragment


    etTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etTime.length() == 0) {
                etTime.setText(" ");
            }
            DialogFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    etTime.setText(Utils.getTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    etTime.setText(null);
                }
            };
            timePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePickerFragment");
        }
    });
//OK button saves EditTexts content

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            task.setTitle(etTitle.getText().toString());
            if (etDate.length() != 0 || etTime.length() != 0) {
                task.setDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            }
            addingTaskListener.onTaskAdded(task);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            addingTaskListener.onTaskAddingCancel();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
// AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            final Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            if (etTitle.length() == 0) {
                positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                tilTitle.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_error_empty_title));
         }

            etTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                        tilTitle.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_error_empty_title));
                    } else {
                        positiveButton.setEnabled(true);
                        tilTitle.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

    return alertDialog;
}
```

}

DatePickerFragment code:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
public DatePickerFragment(){

}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);
}
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
}
```

}

The question is: Did anyone made something like this before? Is here any opportunity to refactor this thing and make it work? PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Get your self `DatePickerFragment.java and MainActivity.java` classes
on DatePickerFragment.java
don't OnDateSetListener interface

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /**Init Calendar**/
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    /**Get Year**/
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    /**Get Month**/
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    /**Get Date of Month**/
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    /**Return a DatePickerDialog**/
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), dateSetListener, year, month, day);
}

 /**Date Set Listener**/
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                /**Show Toast when Select any Date**/
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selected date is " + view.getYear() + " / " + (view.getMonth() + 1) + " / " + view.getDayOfMonth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
```

}

then into **XML **

```
<!--Button to Show a Date Picker Fragment (Dialog)-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="showFragment"
    android:text="Show DialogFragment" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="DatePicker Widget"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

THEN INTO OUR **MainActivity**

```
 public void showFragment(View view) {
           DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
}
```

If this works fine... then extend **DatePickerDialog** class

Comment: I NEED TO USE DatePickerFragment INSIDE  : etDate.OnClickListener (instead of button, that u offered). And all this in OnCreateDialog method, i.e.i use DatePickerFragment inside another DialogFragment (AddingTaskDialogFragment). In MainActivity i call this AddingTaskDialogFragment.